# How to set a date based on a parameter entry

Tags: sql, db2

I'm working on a query that will allow users to pull data based on two parameters, `@START_DATE` AND `@END_DATE`.  However, there is another date column (`ARCHIVE_DATE`) also associated with these dates that doesn't really make sense to anyone in my organization who doesn't have intimate knowledge about how data is stored in our tables.  I basically want to default the `ARCHIVE_DATE` to two months prior to the date entered in the `@START_DATE` parameter.  To make things even more difficult, the `ARCHIVE_DATE` can only be the first date of the month.  So if a user enters '6/15/2015' as the `@START_DATE`, I want the `ARCHIVE_DATE` to default to '4/1/2015'.  I've provided a basic `WHERE` statement below to give you an idea of where I want to put it.

```
WHERE ACCT_NUM = @ACCOUNT_NUMBER
AND BILL_DATE BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE
AND ARCHIVE_DATE = (2 MONTHS PRIOR TO START_DATE AND MUST BE FIRST DATE OF MONTH)
```

Comment: Side note: it's best to always use an exclusive upper bound (`<`) with date/time/timestamp types.  Don't use `BETWEEN` - among other things, the inclusive upper bound (`<=`) makes it difficult or impossible to use safely with timestamps (fancy specifying all those fractional seconds?).  You write and read range queries as "on or after day1 and before day2".

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to subtract 1 less than the current day of the month and then two months.  I think the following is how you implement this logic in DB2:

```
ARCHIVE_DATE = (@START_DATE - (DAY(@START_DATE) - 1) DAYS) - 2 MONTHS
```

A similar method uses `TRUNCATE()`:

```
ARCHIVE_DATE = TRUNCATE(@START_DATE, 'MONTH') - 2 MONTHS
```

Comment: Adding this to the query prompts the following error "SQL0171N  The data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "1" of routine "SYSIBM.DAY" is incorrect. Parameter name: ""."

Comment: @robblob . . . I fixed the first statement, but the second should also work.

Comment: I tried both out and I'm getting ambiguous errors on "DAY" and "TRUNCATE" for both, which is odd because I've used something similar for other date columns in the table, but I've never used them in conjunction with parameters.  Not sure if that is the root of the issue or not.

Comment: @robblob . . . The parameters needs to be declared as a date or converted to one.